# Node.js Express Server with Socket.io 404 Error

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

It’s become clear to me that I am a below average programmer and there is no such thing as a working example of an express/socket.io server on the internet.  Why am I getting this error when I try to load the page?

```
GET http://localhost:3700/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I executed the following command inside of my working directory to install express and socket.io

```
Npm install
```

My package.json file looks like this

```
{
    "name": "RealTimeWebChat",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "Real time web chat",
    "dependencies": {
        "socket.io": "latest",
        "express": "latest",
        "jade": "latest"
    },
    "author": "developer"
}
```

This created a “node_modules” directory, inside of which is a “socket.io” directory.

So why can’t my application find the socket.io.js file?

Other  relevant information, [I’m working off this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socket-io-and-expressjs/).  I’m following it word for word.
I have a .jade file that looks like this.

```
!!!
html
head
    title= "Real time web chat"
    script(src='/chat.js')
    script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    body
        #content(style='width: 500px; height: 300px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; border: solid 1px #999; overflow-y: scroll;')
        .controls
            input.field(style='width:350px;')
            input.send(type='button', value='send')
```

Admittedly, I have no idea what jade is, but I'm just trying to get a simple example up and running.  I learn best as I do.  Final project is due on Sunday!  Help I need a server!

Comment: Please also post your server-side code, it looks like you're not binding Socket.io to the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an end-to-end working example of Express and Socket.io on GitHub at https://github.com/hectorcorrea/intro-to-nodejs

Try this:

```
git clone https://github.com/hectorcorrea/intro-to-nodejs.git
cd intro-to-nodejs
npm install
npm install socket.io
node socketioDemo
```

Then open two browser windows and browse to `http://localhost:3000` and you should be able to exchange messages between the two.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think you are forgetting that I'm a below average programmer.  Can I do this without the github portion?  For example, can I place "intro-to-nodejs-master" inside of a folder called "intro-to-nodejs", then run the npm install commands?  Or do I need to run the npm install command inside of the master directory?

Comment: Ok wait, I removed "master" from the directory, used cd to get inside the directory and performed npm install.  On the right track...

Comment: Wow Hector.  Your demo is the only one I've gotten to work after trying virtually every demo on the web.  Yours worked right away. Time to dissect and try learn.  Thanks!