# socket.IO- why can't my client html page load socket.io.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My server structure is simple. I have a public folder at the same level as my app.'s

```
app.js
node_modules(folder)
   express(folder)
   socket.io(folder)
public(folder)
    index.html
    js(folder)
    css(folder)
```

My app.'s is as follows

```
var sys         = require('sys'),
        express = require('express'),
        app         = express.createServer('127.0.0.1'),
        io          = require('socket.io');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);

var socket = io.listen(app);

socket.on('connection', function (client){
  // new client is here!

 });
```

And my html page(simplified) is

```
<html>
<p id="text">socket.io</p>


<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

When I run the server and load my index.html, socket.io.js is NOT found, a 404 error is generated. What gives?
In my case does socket.IO have to be installed globally?

Comment: Does `socket.io.js` exist in the folder `/public/socket.io/` ?

Comment: Two things. (1) What happens if you remove the leading / from "/socket.io/socket.io". (2) I've got a working example described in this answer that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20426209/446681

Comment: One more thing, file socket.io.js does not have to be in the public folder. This request is automatically processed by socket.io on the server as indicated in this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19521970/446681

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sys     = require('sys'),
    express = require('express'),
    app     = express(),
    io      = require('socket.io');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

var server  = app.listen(3000);
var socket  = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', function (client){
  // new client is here!
});
```

Some explanation:

- `express.createServer` is deprecated, with Express 3 you run `express()` to instantiate
  Express;
- `io.listen` should be passed an `http.Server` instance, whereas you were passing it an Express instance (a `http.Server` instance is returned by `app.listen(...)`);
- there's not need to put the `socket.io.js` file anywhere; `socket.io` installs a handler which watches for requests for that file, and will serve it automatically;